# Arrays.sort comparator issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

**Issue**

Hello, Thanks ahead for anyone willing to help me, I have a problem with sorting an object array in js.

In this component I keep an array inside `this.state` of `id`, `hours`, `day`, and `active`.

My issue is when I try to sort the `object.hours` array the function won't sort by my logics and understanding of this comparator and the array stays same even if the sort expression is `false`.

Which can be found under `sortHoursByTime` declaration.

**Expected Behavior**

`if (obj1.toTime < obj2.fromTime)` then sort the array where `obj1` is first in order.

**Code:**

```
export default class SetWorkingHours extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      workingDays: ['א׳', 'ב׳', 'ג׳', 'ד׳', 'ה׳', 'ו׳'].map((day, _id) => ({
        _id,
        name: day,
        hours: [],
        active: false,
      })),
      activeButton: -1,
    }
  }
  static defaultProps = {};

  sortHoursByTime(day) {
    let sortedDays = day;
    sortedDays.hours.sort((obj1,obj2) => obj1.fromTime < obj2.toTime);
    this.setState({workingDays: sortedDays});
  }

  appendWorkingHours = (hours) => {
    let dateHours = {
      fromTime: this.formatDateToHourString(new Date(hours.fromDate)),
      toTime: this.formatDateToHourString(new Date(hours.toDate))
    };
    let selectedWorkingDays = this.state.workingDays;
    selectedWorkingDays.forEach((day) => {
      if (day.active && this.isHoursValid(day, dateHours)) {
        day.hours.push(dateHours);
        this.sortHoursByTime(day)
      }
    });
    this.setState({workingDays: selectedWorkingDays})
  } // Editor's note: the closing curly brace of appendWorkingHours method 
    // was missing, so I added this line.
};
```

**Environment**

> react-native -v: "0.54.2"
>
> node -v: v9.8.0
>
> npm -v: 5.6.0
>
> yarn --version: 1.5.1
>
> target platform: iOS
>
> operating system: OSX

Comment: The `.sort` comparator function should be returning a number, but yours returns a boolean. Try changing it to `(obj1,obj2) => obj1.fromTime - obj2.toTime`.

Answer (score 2):

When using `Array.sort` in JavaScript with a custom sorting function you need to return `-1` less then, `0` equals, `1` greater then.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

This should fix your issue.

```
sortHoursByTime(day){
    let sortedDays = day;
    // Switch from < to -
    sortedDays.hours.sort((obj1,obj2) => obj1.fromTime - obj2.toTime); 
    this.setState({workingDays: sortedDays});
}
```